# How to update a view from code in an Eclipse RCP app

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a View class (extends `ViewPart`) that contains a `ScrolledForm` created from a `FormToolkit`. When certain events happen in other views in the app I want to change the form in this view and have it update in real time to the user.

I have property change support support added now and the following method in the View

```
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
    form.dispose();
    toolkit.dispose();
    createForm( event );
    form.redraw();
}
```

where `createForm( event )` recreates the form based on the event.

The problem is that the UI does not display the new form after this. I know the form is created OK because if I drag the border between the View and another view to resize it then the View is immediately updated to show the new form. How can I programmatically force the refresh of the view in the UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried: `form.reflow(true);` ?

This will recompute the layout of the form.

If this fails than try calling  `xxx.layout(true)` where 'xxx' is the variable mame of the SWT Composite that is the parent of the form instance. I assume the form is created against its parent composite in your `createForm( event )` method?

Comment: Thanks! your assumption was correct about the parent is correct. Calling reflow alone did not work, but the call to layout(true) on the parent has solved the problem.